# Vector by vector derivative of linear expression

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectors

I have to take the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ of: $$y = Ax + b$$

I am unsure if the answer is supposed to be $A$ or $A^T$. Here is my working of the problem:

$$y_i = \Sigma A_{ij}x_j + b_j$$

$${dy_i\over dx_j} = A_{ij}$$

Where $y$ is a vector of size $m$, and $x$ is a vector of size $n$, so that $A$ is of size $(m,n)$. So is the matrix ${dy\over dx}$ also of size $(m,n)$?

I ask because this comes up in the derivation of "backpropagation for neural networks", where I have terms like ${dy\over dx}$ but they end up being $A^T$ it seems. See more here: http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/09_Neural_Networks_Learning.html

Particularly these images:

[image]

^ This is the model

[image]

^ And this is where derivatives are being taken with respect to the matrix parameters, the $\Theta$s. (i.e. of the linear expression I ask about), and I am confused why the matrices are getting transposed. Though it does make things "work out" in the end, it doesn't fit with the way I tried deriving it.

Thank you for any insight =)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to think of the derivative as the 'best linear approximation' to $f(x+h)-f(x)$.

In this case, you have $f(x) = Ax+b$, hence you have
$f(x+h)-f(x) = Ah$, hence we have $Df(x)(h) = Ah$, which is
sometimes written $Df(x) = A$ when $Df(x)(h)$ can be written
as matrix multiplication.

Comment: In the example I talk about, any idea how we end up getting $\Theta^T$? How is the $D$ operator defined for $f(x)$?